# Send email notifications upon selection of Opportunity picklist

Tags: email

I may be out of luck with this one, but what I'm trying to do is when a user selects certain items from an opportunity picklist, an email gets sent to admins as well as an outside person (non-Salesforce user).  Specifically, when a salesperson updates an Opportunity stage to "client", I want the email notifications to go out.

Is that possible?  And if so, can anybody suggest the best method?

Answer (score 1):

Jeff,

You can specify the external (non Salesforce user) email address in the **additional email address section of the Email alert**. you can specify upto 5 email address in this section.

[Refer here for Email Alert Setup](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm&language=en_US)